# How to reuse an ssh connection

Tags: ssh

I'm creating a small script to update some remote servers (2+)
I am making multiple connects to each server; is there a way I can reuse the SSH connections so I don't have to open too many at once?

Comment: You should add more information about how you're creating the connections to get a better answer: Which language, on which platform, with which library, etc...

Comment: Have you thought about using some sort of provisions like puppet, chef or salt?

Comment: I have a couple servers behind a load balancer. I've got a basic build script working fine; I don't wanna go too far down the rabbit hole if what I've got works. I open a connection to update a certain file, open a connect to git pull, merge, etc etc, and then open a third to update another file

Comment: I would like to integrate the last comment in the question itself to give more useful context (since also nowadays this question is very useful) but the edit queue is full now, as usual to me.

Answer (score 50):

If you open the first connection with `-M`:

```
ssh -M $REMOTEHOST
```

subsequent connections to `$REMOTEHOST` will "piggyback" on the connection established by the master `ssh`. Most noticeably, further authentication is not required. See `man ssh_config` under "ControlMaster" for more details. Use `-S` to specify the path to the shared socket; I'm not sure what the default is, because I configure connection sharing using the configuration file instead.

In my `.ssh/config` file, I have the following lines:

```
host *
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r
```

This way, I don't have to remember to use `-M` or `-S`; `ssh` figures out if a sharable connection already exists for the host/port/username combination and uses that if possible.

This option is available in OpenSSH since 2004.

Comment: There still seems to be a connection lag. Is that expected? I assume subsequent connections don't need the `-M` flag?

Comment: Would something like the following work: `ssh -M -S /tmp/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r -i /path/to/key.pem username@IP`? I ran it without any errors, but the subsequent connections don't seem to be any quicker :/

Comment: Only use the `-M` on the first one, otherwise you create a new master (which needs to authenticate) every time.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm excluding the `-M` in the others. It doesn't seem the file is being created either (tried multiple directories incase it's a permission issue). Strange that it's failing silently?

Comment: Also, the first one needs to stay open while you create the others. One idea is to run `ssh -M -S whatever -N &`, which will open a connection to the remote `sshd` but do nothing else except stay open for the subsequent slave sessions.

Comment: Gotcha. Can I then close it? I don't think I'd want to leave it open indefinitely (or until my config timeout kicks in)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42612/discussion-between-chepner-and-onassar)

Comment: ControlPersist 600 or similar is also sensible. ControlPersist yes|no both have some strange behaviours.

Comment: this will help some but i want to open new terminal with same session instead of local machine..

Comment: @AkhilJalagam That's not something `ssh` can help you with; you need to use a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux` on the remote host.

Comment: tips: if failed with  `Bad owner or permissions on /home/file/.ssh/config`, set the `config` mode to 600, `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`

Comment: fyi. I'm finding this reference to be useful for ssh-connection-sharing background: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-reuse-openssh-connection

Answer (score 21):

Add these lines to `~/.ssh/config` and run `mkdir ~/.ssh/sockets`

```
Host *
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%r@%h-%p
    ControlPersist 600
```

Comment: Unfortunately https://puppetlabs.com/blog/speed-up-ssh-by-reusing-connections no longer shows a blog article; a brief web search also did not yield anything (for me). I see https://web.archive.org/web/20221026175214/https://puppet.com/blog/speed-up-ssh-by-reusing-connections, but the web-page content keeps "disappearing" (I suspect I'm not using web.archive.org properly?). https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-reuse-openssh-connection at first glance looks potentially useful. @Jason - can you help provide guides to any current, helpful references?

Comment: This article has some good information: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-reuse-openssh-connection/

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively, you can do it this way:

```
$ssh_conn="ssh -t -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/master-$$ -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60"

$ssh_conn user@server
```

- `ControlPath=~/.ssh/master-$$` sets up a control path for the ssh
  connection limiting connection reuse to the current shell (via the
  `$$` PID)
- `ControlMaster=auto` allows the connection session to be
  shared using the `ControlPath`
- `ControlPesist=60` sets the amount of
  time the connection should remain open due to inactivity

Answer (score 2):

For modern-distro setups that have a `/run/user/$UID/` for just-this-boot runtime stuff,

```
controlmaster auto
controlpath /run/user/%i/ssh-%C
controlpersist 900
```

at the top of the config (where no match or host restrictions are in effect) will set all ssh sessions that share hosts, port and remote username to use a single connection. I keep `addkeystoagent yes` and `identityfile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519` up there too so ssh doesn't offer all my keys for every host.

Comment: +1 - This answer seems a bit superficial only because it does not use canonical names like "ControlMaster" etc. but it has the plus-value of the "/run/user/" that is a modern pathname to avoid pitfalls after a reboot. I would like to adopt "ControlMaster" with that case etc. but the edit queue is full now, as usual to me.