# git pull/push in a single TCP connection

Tags: git, ssh, tcp, alias

I have a strange network connection that is unreliable sometimes. I will sometimes have to manually press a button every time I want a new TCP connection, which could take up to a minute to reset.

I occasionally use this connection for pushing/pulling git changes.

Most of the time, this works pretty well. I simply `git push` through the connection and my changes go through in a single connection.

However, if there are pending changes on the remote that I don't realise are there, my `git push` will be rejected and I will have to go through a `git pull` and then another `git push`, turning my one connection into three. I could do a `git pull` every time to make sure, but then that usually means an extra connection where one wasn't necessary.

Visual Studio has a term for doing a pull and then a push: "Sync". I am aware that this is not a real git term, but I was wondering if there was a way to set up aliases in such a way that a pull and a push could be done in a single TCP connection. This would make my life much easier.

I am aware that I could keep the connection open using SOCKS, but every layer of networking is costly as this isn't the fastest connection to start with.

Comment: If you can use ssh URLs try [OpenSSH's connection sharing](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Git#ssh-connection-sharing). I use it all the time, not because my network is unreliable but to speed up `git` operations by avoiding reconnecting to the same hosts.

Comment: @phd wow that sounds excellent. If you write an answer about that, I might accept it.

Comment: It's discussed at SO in many Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20410252/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+connection+sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git itself does not have a way to do this: it uses libcurl to open http or https connections, and runs `ssh` to open ssh connections.  For the `git://` protocol it has its own code that uses the OS's socket layer, and makes a new socket.  While libcurl can do persistent connections, it does that on a per-invocation basis, and each Git command starts a new invocation.

Still, a proxy / tunnel would do the trick.  It's up to you to decide whether the extra overhead is worthwhile.